# Extract data from pdf invoices of varying formats

Tags: pdf, data-extraction, pdf-extraction

The objective is to extract data out of invoices in pdf format.

Pdf data format:
selectable text (not scanned images) consists of lines of text, name-value pairs, tables (of varying lengths)

Invoices data includes:
invoice_no, invoice_date, order_no, order_date in name-value pairs
items details (item_code, name, rate, quantity, discount, price, etc) in table format
final_taxation_info and gross_total

Inputs:
Bulk of invoices are received weekly having both similar and distinct formats

Outputs:
Extract invoices data and insert into database

Approaches tried or considered so far:

1. Writing a **custom algorithm** in C# using libraries, like iText7, PDFix, GemBox.Pdf, GroupDocs.Parser, Bytescout.PDFExtractor, Sautinsoft.pdffocus, Spire.PDF, etc.
   *Downside: Have to modify or write a new algorithm for a new pdf format.*
2. **Data extraction tools**, like SmallPDF, Convertapi.com, cometdocs.com, groupdocs.app.
   *Downside: No control over the extraction algorithm.*
3. **Template guided extraction**, like Pdf_Element, Tabula, Docparser, iText pdf2Data.
   *Downside: Fails when the table length varies.*
4. **AI/ML**-based extraction, **automation tools**/services, like AWS Textract, UiPath, KlearStack, IQ Bot (I have not tried this last approach practically in-depth, just scratched the surface).
   *Downside: Not sure but seems like learning curve or cost could be stumbling blocks.*

Considering this whole scenario can anybody suggest which approach I should follow.

Answer (score 1):

We used approach 1, at our org, you have to come up with 
pdf->free text-> formulated exprressions to extract.
AI tools would work only if you have a large set of documents that you can "train" the AI with .

```
http://www.puntechsolutions.com.au/smartdt.html
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jyotheendra, I have started off with approach 1, writing algorithms in C# harnessing iText7 library to extract pdf data. It appears very tedious, but also offers more control over the process.
May I ask which platform and library you used for writing extraction algorithm?

Comment: Hi @AmitBhagat, We used PDFbox -> text->algo all in Java, the Java algorithm was our area to fcous, and once we figured out proper way to template and find text matches, it beacame easy .

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Jyotheendra. Currently, I am developing in C#, I will check out PDFbox, seems like they have provided an assembly in .Net on NuGet.